jenkins fails for docker plugin
I am using
docker.image(container_url).inside('-u root --platform linux/arm64') {
    sh 'ls -al'
    dir(path_to_bin_dir) { 
         call_my_function()
    }

I have the qemu container starting before i do docker.image.
my ls -al returns nothing (empty). It is supposed to have my code base directory downloaded and the path_to_bin_dir dir inside is also existing.
I downloaded the image and ran it, I see everything nicely laid out (this is all manual process). Why can't jenkins see it?
this is the output of my ls command
floppy 4096 Nov 14 21:33 .
floppy 4096 Nov 14 21:33 ..

TIA
